# I saw what's yours

Tags: language, connect-wall

Pair up the following ten words:

- Arabic
- french fries
- gray
- monthly
- ninety-nine
- paying
- rent
- smooth
- whatever
- yellow

Hint, added later:

> Knowledge of a specific non-English language will prove helpful.

Another hint, added even later:

> Knowledge of a specific non-English language will prove helpful. But that language is native to an area of the world in which English is the primary language.

Another hint, added even later:

> Knowledge of a specific non-English language will prove helpful. But that language is native to an area of the world in which English is the primary language, though it's descendant from a language that's native to an area of the world in which French is the primary language.

Comment: Do you mean language with "non-Latin script" by saying "non-English" language?

Comment: @JohnBrookfields , no.

Comment: What do you mean by "native"? Like "primarily used by original inhabitants"?

Comment: @iBug the language is originally from there

Comment: @msh210 which existing answer do you want to reward? :)

Comment: @bobble I picked that bounty reason for kicks. My real bounty reason is to get eyes on this and, I hope, an answer.

Comment: Nz V ba gur evtug genpx be pbzcyrgryl bss vs V guvax gur ynathntr lbh'er ersreevat gb vf perbyr be npnqvna/pnwha creuncf?

Comment: @Prim3numbah the latter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking at this for a long time (and 'looking' is the key word here!) I think the words should be paired up as follows:

> Arabic + yellow
>  french fries + ninety-nine
>  gray + whatever
>  monthly + rent
>  paying + smooth

Because:

> in [**American Sign Language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language), the signs for these paired items are very similar!
>
>  *Note re the Hints:* ASL, here, is a 'non-English' language native to the USA (where English is the primary language). However, it is descendant in part from Old French Sign Language, which is (of course) native to French-speaking countries of the world :)

While I am not au fait with the general terminology surrounding this language, here is an attempt to describe the pairings in an understandable way...

> [**Yellow**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/yellow) is signed by making a fist with your thumb and little finger extended (ASL for 'Y') and rotating the hand back and forth. I have been unable to find a video for '**Arabic**' online, but did manage to find [this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asl/comments/2jlt6s/how_do_you_say_arabic/) where a user conveniently describes signing this word as "very much like 'yellow' but with a much tighter shake"!
>
>  [**French fries**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/french-fries) is signed by forming a circle with your thumb and forefinger and dipping it twice, which is very similar to the sign for [**ninety-nine**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/99).
>
>  [**Gray**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/gray) is signed by wafting your stretched out hands past each other, palms towards your chest, in a similar fashion to the sign for [**whatever**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/whatever).
>
>  [**Monthly**](https://www.signasl.org/sign/monthly) is signed by stroking one forefinger down the other twice. This is an identical motion to that for [**rent**](https://aslteachingresources.com/dictionary/rent/).
>
>  There appear to be several ways to sign **Paying** online, but some of them are very similar to one of the (again) many signs for [**smooth**](https://www.handspeak.com/word/search/index.php?id=2001), involving sliding your hands forward while passing the thumb and a finger over each other.

This solution also makes sense of the title - after all:

> ASL is all about **seeing** the words!

Comment: Correct! Well done. (And the title was a reference to the song lyric "I saw the sign" and the common question "what's your sign". Probably too oblique.)

Comment: Ah should have got this one!! Very nice job